# scraping a web flyer

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am Scraping a web flyer

https://flipp.com/flyers/groceries

```
POSTAL CODE N2L2A1
```

however, though all the items are coded in HTML with same tags and class names, I am unable to scrape everything in selenium.

I have tried find_elements method but still can scrape only one value, conceptually it shouldn't be the case.

since I am using common class name, everything should be listed.

That's not the case here. Am I missing something?

My code looks like this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//html/body/flipp-dialog/div/flipp-toast-container/div/flipp-item-dialog/div/h2/span")
```

Comment: my thoughts are...looks like each image is a clickable tab and all these clickable tag links are given in a single page which is the above link.

Comment: The link does not work for me - 404 uh oh unexpected error

Comment: hi Martin, thanks for trying. you can try this https://flipp.com/flyers/groceries

Answer (score 3):

Xpath you chose is a problem.

1. Usually you should avoid absolute xpath. Choose relative xpath instead, starting from the item that actually has a meaning for you.
2. Make sure you select an element, which actually exists on page. Sometimes it means you need to hover or click on something, before that element is available. For instance when I searched for `flipp-toast-container` on that page you provided in the comment, all it has is:

   ```
   <flipp-toast-container global=""><flipp-toast></flipp-toast><div class="toastable-content"></div></flipp-toast-container>
   ```

   So it won't select anything meaningful.

So if you want to select each and every flyer name on page that lists them (e.g. flipp.com/flyers/groceries), use xpath like this:

```
//flipp-flyer-listing-item//p[@class="flyer-name"]
```

(i.e.: we select `flipp-flyer-listing-item`, which represents container for each flyer; and choose `p` with  attribute `@class=flyer-name`; we skip any levels in between with `//`, since it's only important to locate those 2 items in relation to each other, it doesn't matter where they are on page.

If your goal is to actually scrape contents of each flyer (page like https://flipp.com/flyer/1352064-zehrs-weekly-flyer), you will have to navigate to contents of the flyer first, and then choose each item as:

```
//flipp-flyerview//a[@class="item-container"]/div
```

Note: there are also methods other than xpath to choose the item, and I'm leaving aside navigation topic, since it's not part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here the easy way to parse Flipp flyers. In this example, your browser will return application/json content type.

```
https://backflipp.wishabi.com/flipp/items/search?locale=[Your Language preference here]&postal_code=[Your postal code here]&q=[Your merchant here]

//in this example you will get all items (description, price, image etc..) from all valid flyers from Walmart in in the area of  H4A1B9 postal code

https://backflipp.wishabi.com/flipp/items/search?locale=en-ca&postal_code=H4A1B9&q=Walmart

//in this example you will search at Walmart for a specifific item

https://backflipp.wishabi.com/flipp/items/search?locale=en-ca&postal_code=H4A1B9&q=Walmart AND milk
```

//in this example you will search all merchants for a specifific item

```
https://backflipp.wishabi.com/flipp/items/search?locale=en-ca&postal_code=H4A1B9&q=milk
```

Comment: Does flipp have any docs on their api because I am trying to query by upc code instead of the product name

Comment: @Chris Did either of you find API documentation? They don't appear to broadcast their API endpoint publicly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the locator correction, also consider that find_elements... (plural variant) should be returning a list that you should be able to iterate through. Given that, you shouldn't even have to sweat the offsets too much.